# I have netbook with an atom N450 and DDR3 Does this make sense?

Tags: netbook, ddr3, intel-atom

Is this possible or [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) got it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible. Pineview  supports DDR3